# Automating putty with .bat file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, putty

I'm trying to automate running multiple  UNIX commands in PUTTY by creating .bat file. I used following command to login :

```
putty.exe -ssh [domain name] -l [username] -pw [password] -m cmd.txt
```

where cmd.txt has commands (like cd) to execute after logging in. I'm able to logging in successfully but no operations are performed after that.

Comment: Show us (a representative snippet of) `cmd.txt` and explain what you expect it to accomplish.  Chances are you are attempting to paste things into the shell where it's not expecting them.

Comment: i want to change directory so i have typed only this line in cmd.txt  "cd \spec_folder"

Comment: The purpose of the `-m` option seems to be to run a command and then exit, if I'm reading the [documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.68/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline) correctly.  (It's not very explicit about this and I (luckily) don't have Windows anywhere nearby so I can't test.)